# Sqlite3 get select limit values C++

Tags: c++, mysql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3.

Now I am selecting top 5 records from a table.
 Like that:

```
int Main()
{
    sqlite3 * db;
    sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
    sqlite3_prepare(db, "SELECT * FROM [PLAYERLEVEL] ORDER BY [Level] Desc LIMIT 5;", -1, &stmt, NULL);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    int GetLevel = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1);
    return GetLevel;
}
```

Now GetLevel variable is getting only the first highest record stored on PLAYERLEVEL table, how can I get all the values I wanted while using LIMIT 5.

```
Example:
Top record Level = 88.
2nd Highest record level = 87.
3rd Highest record level = 82.
How can I get 87? and how can I get 82?
```

Thank you

Comment: Obviously not real code.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: int Main() is not valid C++. If that's not real, so probably is other stuff.

Comment: well the code is totally different on source, the int main has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: What? If the code is totally different from what you posted, how are we supposed to answer questions about it?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5456/sqlite3-stmt-prepared-statement-c-api/19406/reading-data-from-a-cursor).